# style tab functions in input tab

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there any way to move/include style fuctions like - Line thickness and Shapes options to Input tab?

[Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/KcdNKZmr/Untitled-1.jpg)

[pine-script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sxq7EY4OfMK6M9nFWFMjPOJgmjQkO2gV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please don't post your code as a link. Instead, copy&paste it here and use the code formatting options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move but you can do some tricks.

Set the `editable` parameter of your `plot` function to `false`. This way it will not appear in the style tab.

Then create user inputs for each fature you want the user to modify via the inputs section.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

in_width = input.int(1, "Width", minval=1)
in_color = input.color(color.green, "Color")
in_shape = input.string(shape.circle, "Shape", [shape.circle, shape.diamond])

is_last = barstate.islast

plotshape(is_last, "Shape", in_shape, location.abovebar, in_color, editable=false)
plot(close, "Close", in_color, in_width, editable=false)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. These are your [options](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/):

```
input.bool
input.color
input.float
input.int
input.price
input.session
input.source
input.string
input.symbol
input.text_area
input.time
input.timeframe
```

The "style" tab is exclusively tradingview generated and internally generated. The "inputs" tab is for pine script users where your inputs (see above) appear. Only these types can be used and defined by yourself.